# Is there any way to inject Interceptor from external library in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, web, aop, interceptor

I'm developing a jar library and trying to inject an interceptor from external jar library to Application.

For example:

#### External Lib

##### MyExternalInterceptor.java

```java
public class MyExternalInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I tried to using AOP in external libs but it's not working.

#### InterceptorAspect.java

```java
@Around("execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addInterceptors(..))")
public Object aspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // Tried to inject MyExternalInterceptor here
    Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    return result;
}
```

In Application using that lib:

### Application

#### MyConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
public MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new SpringTestInterceptor()); // client's own interceptor
        /* Add MyExternalInterceptor not explicitly but implicitly using AOP or other things */
    }
}
```

Is there any way to inject an interceptor from external lib to App?

I know the question is very obscure (sorry for that), but could you give me any advice or hint to make it work?

Thank you for anyone who read my question :)

(I updated few more details for clarification)

Comment: Try annotating `SpringTestInterceptor` as an `@Component`, and inject as a parameter to `addInterceptors(...)`.

Comment: Just add a `WebMvcConfigurer` (**not** `WebMvcConfigurerSupport`!) that is annotated with `@Configuration` to register the interceptors you want to be registered. Users of your library should scan/use that config class. You will need to call the `addInterceptor` else nothing will be added.

Comment: Hi @AndrewS , thanks for the answer!
Actually, I'd like to inject `MyExternalInterceptor` (not `SpringTestInterceptor`) - sorry for make you confused.

Comment: What a surprise! You save my day @M.Deinum!
It's really work like a magic!
I really appreciate to you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

- Use `WebMvcConfigurer` in both Client and library side instead of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`
- AoP is not needed

I use `WebMvcConfigurer` instead of `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and change some codes like below:

#### External Lib

##### MyExternalInterceptor.java

- Same as before

##### InterfaceAspect.java

- Don't needed it anymore

##### MyExternalLibConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
public class MyExternalLibConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyExternalInterceptor());
    }
}
```

#### Application (client)

##### MyConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
public MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new SpringTestInterceptor()); // client's own interceptor
        /* No need to add MyExternalInterceptor in here */
    }
}
```

That's all! Everything is working well as [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) said in comment.

Thank you again Deinum!

Comment: Ehrm... YOu don't need all of that. You **only&& need that `MyConfiguration`... No AOP is needed. Just included that configuration in your library and it will be automatically used (and remove the `@EnableWebMvc` that should be part of the client app not your library code). The aspect might not even run if AspectJ proxying is disabled on the app using it, nor should you have your library depend on aspectj...

Comment: Ohh.. I got it.
So, you means that
- `implements WebMvcConfigurer` & implements `addInterceptors(..)` in `Configuration.java` of library side
- Just change to `WebMvcConfigurer` in `Configuration.java` of client side

Is that right?

Comment: No. For your library include a class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` annotate it with `@Configuration` (although I suspect `@Component` might work as well) and register your interceptor. That class will be detected by the client app and this will participate in configuring Spring MVC and thus register the interceptor.

Comment: Okay, then the answer that i wrote is correct?
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/71019792/7110084)

Comment: If you want to make it easier, and support Spring Boot, you could also add a `spring.factories` class (like described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration). Then for Spring Boot the only thing that needs to be added is your jar, everything else will be automatic (no dependency on component scanning to detect your configuration class).